# C# UWP ToggleSwitch in ListView

Tags: c#, xaml, listview, uwp, toggleswitch

Suppose you have the `ListView` below :

```
<ListView x:Name="ListViewActiveAssets" Margin="10,10,10,10" CanReorderItems="True" AllowDrop="True" CanDragItems="True" SelectionMode="Extended" DragItemsStarting="ListViewActiveAssets_DragItemsStarting" DragItemsCompleted="ListViewActiveAssets_DragItemsCompleted">
<ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:DataType="local:Asset">
        <Grid VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="36" />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="108" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <TextBlock Text="&#xE700;" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind AssetType}" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name}" Grid.Column="2" FontSize="18" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind StartDate}" Grid.Column="3" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
            <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind EndDate}" Grid.Column="4" FontSize="16" VerticalAlignment="Center" Padding="0,0,5,0"/>
            <ToggleSwitch Grid.Column="8" x:Name="ToggleSwitchEnable" IsOn="{x:Bind IsEnabledSwitch}" OnContent="On" OffContent="Off" Padding="5,0" Toggled="ToggleSwitchEnable_Toggled"/>

        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

This `ListBox` can be reordered and this work fine. I simply would like to know why the `Toggled` event is fired when I reorder an item in `ListView` ?

Indeed, my `Toggled` event contains code that refresh the `ListView`, so when I'am dragging item, the `ListView` refreshes and the drag&drop fail.

If someone have a suggestion... Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have Binding on ToggleSwitch. Does your `IsEnabledSwitch` as `PropertyChanged` on it? also Is your collection `ObservableCollection`?

Comment: No the `IsEnabledSwitch` doesn't have `PropertyChanged` and yes it's an `ObservableCollection`

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a local bool in your class and set it to false in your constructor:

```
private bool toggling;

public myPage()
{
    toggling = false;
}
```

Then, in your OnToggled method, start by setting toggling to true and then set it back to false at the end of the method.

```
void ToggleSwitchEnable_Toggled(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    toggling = true;
    // Your code
    toggling = false;
}
```

You can then set your refresh method to only execute when toggling is false:

```
void refresh()
{
    if(toggling)
        return;
    //Your code
}
```

This will cause the refresh command to be skipped whenever you toggle the switch

Comment: Just noticed that I think you want that to not refresh when you are dragging, not toggling.  To achieve that, do the same but instead of in your Toggled method, do so in you DragItemsStarting method

Comment: Thanks it's a great idea to work around this problem but there isn't only the toggle switch that can refresh the list. So I have to enable/disable this variable on each events.
For now I solve this because when event was triggered on drag&drop, the value of the switch isn't changed (this is even stranger), so I can test this to not refresh my `ListView`.